# jquery conflict in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

i make plugin for site for jquery i am use google jquery  for that i am using the code

```
/*add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'include_jquery' ) );

function include_jquery(){


                   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
                   wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"));
                   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');


            }*/
```

but it conflict width my header file jquery so wat i do to solved it

Comment: **PHP** tag seems extra to me in this question.

Comment: this is wordpress and i am get jquery of google by php that y i used php tag

Answer (score 1):

simply add jquery to your theme's header.php file in between head tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use the jQuery function 'noConflict' which allows multiple versions/instances of jQuery.

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

EDIT, try:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i am use above code to prevent conflict but it is not working so how i should use noConflict in this code